# Copycopter - different flag instead of t

Tags: copycopter

I want copycopter to recognize a blurb only when I specifically pass in some sort of `copter` flag or something like that.  I do not want it to offer a blurb for every `t` call.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a very messy solution for anyone who wants to try it out, but I really don't think it is ideal.  I basically went into the copycopter's server code and in the `ProjectsController` under the method `show` at the bottom I added

```
@localizations = @localizations.joins(:blurb).where("blurbs.key ~* ?",".copter")
```

which then takes all the localizations and cuts down the ones that don't have ".copter" in their key.  Now all you need to do in your client is add ".copter" in the key for any localizations you want to show up.  It's hacky but it works.